# Binning state time of a device by day using Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binning

I have a Pandas dataframe of power enable/disable commands vs time.  The index is not in-use at the moment.  You can create it on your own with this:

```py
pd.DataFrame(
    {'command_timestamp': {
        0: pd.Timestamp('2023-08-01 15:39:42'),
        1: pd.Timestamp('2023-08-02 03:30:39'),
        2: pd.Timestamp('2023-08-02 16:09:35'),
        4: pd.Timestamp('2023-08-02 17:30:16'),
        5: pd.Timestamp('2023-08-02 17:32:05'),
        6: pd.Timestamp('2023-08-02 17:45:43'),
        7: pd.Timestamp('2023-08-03 17:48:01'),
        8: pd.Timestamp('2023-08-03 18:20:11'),
        9: pd.Timestamp('2023-08-04 18:49:37'),
        10: pd.Timestamp('2023-08-07 21:13:05')},
     'command': {
        0: 'enable',
        1: 'disable',
        2: 'enable',
        4: 'enable',
        5: 'enable',
        6: 'disable',
        7: 'enable',
        8: 'disable',
        9: 'enable',
        10: 'disable'}})
```

[image: My dataframe.]

#### What I am trying to do

I need to calculate the "ON time" of the device by day.  Imagine that the actual data set is much larger than this example set.  I cannot seem to come up with good solution, much less one that doesn't involve iterating through the dataframe and checking a load of `if` statements.

Some assumptions and things to consider:

- Consecutive enable or disable commands can be ignored (i.e. if the device is already ON, another 'enable' won't do anything, and there are no missing commands).
- While, given the previous point, we can't know for sure, we will assume that if the *first command* of the dataset is "enable", the device was OFF all day prior to that.

  - Similarly, if the *first command* was "disable", we will assume it was ON all day up to that point.
- If the *last command* of the dataset was "enable", we will assume the device was ON for the remainder of the day.
- If it is turned on one day and not turned off until the next day (or multiple days later), the time ON for day one should go until midnight, and the time ON for the following days should start at midnight.  Put another way, a single day shouldn't have more than 24hr of ON time.

For a little context, this is for representing "daily utilization" of the device rather than counting "consecutive on-time" etc..

#### Sample data expected results

Here is a manual calculation of the example dataset:

```py
results = {
    '2023-08-01': (
        pd.Timestamp('2023-08-02 00:00:00') - 
        pd.Timestamp('2023-08-01 15:39:42')),
    
    '2023-08-02': (
        pd.Timestamp('2023-08-02 03:30:39') - 
        pd.Timestamp('2023-08-02 00:00:00')
        ) + (
        pd.Timestamp('2023-08-02 17:45:43') - 
        pd.Timestamp('2023-08-02 16:09:35')
        ), 
    '2023-08-03': (
        pd.Timestamp('2023-08-03 18:20:11') - 
        pd.Timestamp('2023-08-03 17:48:01')
        ), 
    '2023-08-04': (
        pd.Timestamp('2023-08-05 00:00:00') - 
        pd.Timestamp('2023-08-04 18:49:37')
        ), 
    '2023-08-05': (
        pd.Timestamp('2023-08-06 00:00:00') - 
        pd.Timestamp('2023-08-05 00:00:00')
        ), 
    '2023-08-06': (
        pd.Timestamp('2023-08-07 00:00:00') - 
        pd.Timestamp('2023-08-06 00:00:00')
        ), 
    '2023-08-07': (
        pd.Timestamp('2023-08-07 21:13:05') - 
        pd.Timestamp('2023-08-07 00:00:00')
        )
}
```

[image: Sample dataset results.]

Comment: It sounds like your data spans multiple days, but then why infer the overnight state based on the first command in the morning, especially when the same command can be given consecutively?

Comment: whats the expected output for the sample data?

Comment: I think you can just order it by timestamp, compute the differences between each consecutive timestamp, and sum the ones preceded by "enable".

Comment: @QuangHoang editted to add expected output.

Comment: @Joe the device is often left on overnight, so I wouldn't really call it an inference.  Maybe I'm not following your reasoning though.

Comment: So in your data, there won't be two consecutive `enable` belonging to two different days?  For example, the last `enable` of day 1 is followed by the first `enable` of day 3?

Comment: @QuangHoang no that’s entirely possible. That would simply mean that the device was commanded ON on day 1, left on all day on day 2, and then commanded ON again on day 3 (which would have no effect as it is already ON). It stays on until it receives a ‘disable’.

Comment: It's occurred to me that you all might be pointing out that if duplicate consecutive commands are allowed, there is no reason to trust that the very first command in the dataset resulted in a change of state.  I updated the question to clarify that this particular point would be an assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I now think I understand your question. First, create fictitious entries to mark your day boundaries.

```
df = pd.concat([
    df.set_index('command_timestamp'),
    df.reindex(pd.date_range(
        start=df['command_timestamp'].min().date(),
        end=df['command_timestamp'].max().date(),
        freq='D'))
]).sort_index()
```

(I assume start is `disable`.) Then assume that the last state carries forward to the fictitious day boundary. Then do the differencing. You must pass `to_series` to access the right function.

```
df['command'] = df['command'].ffill().fillna('disable')
df['diff'] = df.index.to_series().diff().shift(-1)
```

A group by the date along with a filtered summation then yields your desired outcome:

```
>>> df.groupby(df.index.to_series().dt.date) \
...     .apply(lambda d: d.loc[d['command'] == 'enable', 
...                            'diff'].sum())
2023-08-01   0 days 08:20:18
2023-08-02   0 days 05:06:47
2023-08-03   0 days 00:32:10
2023-08-04   0 days 05:10:23
2023-08-05   1 days 00:00:00
2023-08-06   1 days 00:00:00
2023-08-07   0 days 21:13:05
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

Explanatory note. Prior to the group by summation, the relevant columns of the data frame look like this:

```
                     command            diff
2023-08-01 00:00:00  disable 0 days 15:39:42
2023-08-01 15:39:42   enable 0 days 08:20:18
2023-08-02 00:00:00   enable 0 days 03:30:39
2023-08-02 03:30:39  disable 0 days 12:38:56
2023-08-02 16:09:35   enable 0 days 01:20:41
2023-08-02 17:30:16   enable 0 days 00:01:49
2023-08-02 17:32:05   enable 0 days 00:13:38
2023-08-02 17:45:43  disable 0 days 06:14:17
2023-08-03 00:00:00  disable 0 days 17:48:01
2023-08-03 17:48:01   enable 0 days 00:32:10
2023-08-03 18:20:11  disable 0 days 05:39:49
2023-08-04 00:00:00  disable 0 days 18:49:37
2023-08-04 18:49:37   enable 0 days 05:10:23
2023-08-05 00:00:00   enable 1 days 00:00:00
2023-08-06 00:00:00   enable 1 days 00:00:00
2023-08-07 00:00:00   enable 0 days 21:13:05
2023-08-07 21:13:05  disable             NaT
```

It may be more didactic to read `diff` instead as `time_elapsed`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!  I hadn't ever used `df.groupby()` before - feels like I will definitely make more use of it in the future.  For anyone following, I made the following modifications: 1) Add one day to the `end` parameter in `pd.date_range()` so that the ON time of the last day can be calculated; 2) Set the first `command` entry (after concatenating in the beginning of day rows) to the opposite of the second (the original first sample); 3) Run `.fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))` on the final series output by `groupby.apply()`.